# Textbox hidden with javascript becomes visible when other events occur

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

When a dropdown value is changed (from ddlSource), I have javascript that will hide few text boxes, which is working fine. Next, when the user enters a certain value in an other textbox, I have a ajax call to populate few labels. After this ajax call when the form loads, the hidden text boxes are now visible. Where have I gone wrong?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSource" runat="server" 
                  TabIndex="80" EnableViewState="True" CssClass="Input" 
                  Width="162px" onchange="DisableEnable();">

    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="x" Value="x" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="y" Value="y" />

</asp:DropDownList>
```

and my javascript for enabledisable is

```
function DisableEnable() {
    var DropDown_Source = document.getElementById("<%= ddlSource.ClientID %>")

    if (DropDown_Source.options[DropDown_Source.selectedIndex].text == "y") {

        document.getElementById('txtSupplementNbr').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById("txtDelDate").style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('lblSupplementNbr').style.display = '';
        document.getElementById('lblDelDate').style.display = '';
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById("txtSupplementNbr").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("txtDelDate").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('lblSupplementNbr').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('lblDelDate').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

The textbox that makes the ajax call

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="UpdatePaneltxtTrialCaseNbr" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTrialCaseNbr" runat="server" Text="" tabindex="100" 
                     Width="200px" maxlength="120" cssclass="input" 
                     OnTextChanged="GetCaseSummaryCivilPlaintiffInfo"  
                     onblur="SearchTrialCaseNbr();GetCasePlaintiffInfo();" 
                     AutoPostBack="false" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

After it it executes the `OnTextChanged()` function, I see all the controls that were hidden before. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can we see the code for your `GetCaseSummaryCivilPlaintiffInfo` function?

Answer (score 0):

The html is re-rendered due to ajax request to its initial state. Call `DisableEnable()` on ajax request `ends` using [Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager endRequest Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to update state of form elements.

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args)
{
     DisableEnable();
}
```

You can also put all the controls that change in update panel so that their state is maintained by asp.net between ajax calls.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't the update panel only re-render elements within it's content template? When I used to use them (although I've since moved to using javascript ajax calls instead), only my javascript variables that referenced elements within the update panels needed to be redefined on the endRequest event.

Comment: There is only textbox in update panel and it does not mean any changes in said objects, bit confusing.

Comment: Those are my thoughts exactly. I believe the issue may be a bug in his `GetCaseSummaryCivilPlaintiffInfo` function. The main difference I see is his omission of the `()` after the javascript function, but I cannot recall if this is code-breaking. I asked him to post this function just in case.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to handle visibility AND display in your toggling function. The primary difference is that visibility hides the element but maintains it's position, get rid of it. Display value should work fine for you.  Here is a simpler display toggling script as well, pass it an object and it will check to see if it is already displayed or not.

```
function toggle(obj) {
    var el = document.getElementById(obj);
    if ( el.style.display != 'none' ) {
        el.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        el.style.display = '';
    }
}
```

Now you just want to make sure this is only called when you want it to, and onchange will continue to toggle the display.  I believe @Adil's response will manage that portion of your question.